# NoSuchElementException when trying to read integers from a file?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read integers from a .txt file and I get this error directly after input even though the while loop contains hasNextInt to make sure there is another integer in the file to read.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Part2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String prompt = ("Please input the name of the file to be opened: ");
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String fileName = input.nextLine();
    input.close();
    Scanner reader = null;

    try{
      reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); 
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("--- File Not Found! Exit program! ---"); 
    }

    int num = 0;
    while(reader.hasNextInt()){
      reader.nextInt();
      num++;
    }

    int[] list = new int[num];
    for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
      list[i] = reader.nextInt(); 
    }

    reader.close();

    System.out.println("The list size is: " + num);
    System.out.println("The list is:");
    print(list);//Method to print out
    }//main
}//Part2
```

Comment: 1. `print(list);`?? seems lost, definitely something is missing in there.

Comment: Sorry, that's a method later on in the code

Answer (score 1):

This is because in while loop , you have reached the end of the file.

```
 while(reader.hasNextInt()){
          reader.nextInt();
          num++;
        }
```

try to reinitialize it again after the while loop.

```
 reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `List` like

```
List list = new ArrayList();
int num = 0;
while(reader.hasNextInt()){
  list.add(reader.nextInt());
  num++;
}

/* this part is unnecessary
int[] list = new int[num];
for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
  list[i] = reader.nextInt(); 
}
*/
//then
System.out.print(list);
```

Comment: List list = new ArrayList(); can be changed to List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();